# My linux bash $$ doesn't match /proc/self link?

Tags: linux, bash, process, pid, proc

I'm on RHEL 5 and tried /proc like this:

```
$echo $$
50040

$ls -ld /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 64 Jan 22 15:25 /proc/self -> 22485
```

I expected that /proc/self link to a subdirectory of /proc that's my current process id. But $$ shows process id is 50040, not 22485. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PID you are seeing when issuing the `ls` command is the one for the `ls` command, not that of your shell.  If you do it many times in a row, you will see it is different each time:

```
fred> ls -ld /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 12 13:13 /proc/self -> 5075

fred> ls -ld /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 12 13:13 /proc/self -> 5076

fred> ls -ld /proc/self
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 12 13:13 /proc/self -> 5077
```

If you want to get the PID of the shell, you need to make sure you use `/proc/self` when the shell is running, not one of its sub-processes:

```
cd /proc/self ; pid=$(awk '{print $1}' stat) ; cd -
```

(the `cd` is a `bash` internal command so, at the point where you access `/proc/self`, you're still running in the shell process itself).

Comment: @paxdiablo  Thanks for the improvements.  I am quite new to this site.  Are there general guidelines to how/when one should (or should not) edit someone else's posts (for instance as opposed to providing a separate answer)?

Comment: Fred, in this case, the crux of my answer was the same as yours (`ls` is a subprocess so will have a different `self`) so I saw no point in repeating that. So I just added some extra details (examples basically showing that your contention was right, it's always good to support contentions with some hard evidence). Then I just went mad and added a way to get the same result as with `$$`. I think I should probably stop now. Bottom line, my intent is to get the best answers, not more (increasingly irrelevant) rep for myself :-)

Comment: The tour states it best (http://stackoverflow.com/tour): `Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them. Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `man proc`.  The `/proc/self` refers to the process accessing the `/proc` filesystem and not the id of the shell (which is what `$$` is returning and would be the parent of `/proc/self`).